# How to use streams in abstract classes

Tags: c++, file, stream, iostream

This might seem like an opinion question but I'm really looking for some good ways to go about doing this. so what's this? I basically want to have an abstract class named `Repo` let's say. This class is going to define the abstraction for what a `Repo` should be capable of doing. In this case, I just want to be able to save something, say you provide a name and data and it's supposed to store it for you. Then we can have a `FileRepository` that would save them on disc, `S3Repository` for example to store them in the AWS S3, or even `MemoryRepository` where we just save them in the memory.

Great, but how do I abstract this out? obviously I could get the bytes and each derived class would use their own stream to save it but what if the data is large and we don't want to load it up in the memory? let's say we want to save a 5GB file, we don't want to load that up in the memory.

I looked at the AWS SDK for C++ and it seems like they take a lambda with an ostream in it so you can write content. I tried to mimic something like that here so you can either just pass your `istream`, or give a lambda that takes an `ostream` and does whatever its heart desires.

Just wondering if there is a better way for this? it's often difficult to find good practices in c++ since there are a billion ways to do the same thing and many people do things very differently. I'd just love some insight here. I'm fairly new to C++ so a good explanation would be highly appreciated.

```
class Repo {
public:
  virtual void add_with_ostream(const string& name, const std::function<void (ostream&)>& f) = 0;

  template<typename T>
  void add(const string& name, const T& data) {
    this->add_with_ostream(name, [&data](ostream& output_stream) {
      output_stream << data;
    });
  }

  virtual void add_with_istream(const string&name, const istream& input_stream) {
    this->add_with_ostream(name, [&input_stream](ostream& output_stream) {
      output_stream << input_stream.rdbuf();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: There's nothing in the description that calls for template usage. Based on the given description, `FileRepository` and `MemoryRepository` should be simple subclasses of `Repo`. This is what subclasses are for.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I understand that, I'm more asking about whether or not the abstract class is designed properly. The template I have is just to be able to capture different types like int, string, etc. it'll just be piped to the output streams.

Comment: Of course not. If this class is supposed to have a `FileRepository` subclass, that handles everything related to file-based storage, then the abstract class should have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with any `std::ostream`, as shown here.  That's the subclass's job.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Serialize/DeSerialize your objects?

Comment: I thought `ostream` was the base class for output streams. What type should the abstract class use then? cause the abstract class still has to provide the methods so we need to know what to take as input parameter. My thought was that `FileRepository` would implement the `add_with_ostream` and pass a file stream as the `ostream` and the `MemoryRepo` would use a stringstream for example. The abstract would just provide some helper methods but all of them are relying on `add_with_ostream` which something the derived class has to provide.

Comment: @MartinYork not serialization, just storing data. There is going to be a class that needs to load up configs, use some strange inheritance logic to compile another set of configs, this manager class could be using JSON, XML or whatever format it pleases to use. Point is: these configs could be loaded from local files if on devices like android, or database or S3 in other places. We could easily add in support for different storages if we use this abstraction. W'd basically just implement a `Repo` and then let the rest of the code remain as is. Separation of concern if you will.

Comment: @Peyman: The abstraction here is the stream. You can pass it a file stream / memory stream / S3 stream / DB stream / Arbitrary new stream. Then you serialize the object to the stream.

Comment: If it smells like a database, a database should be used. :-)